# Java Timer.Schedule (infiniti loop) stop running

Tags: java, loops, timer, infinite-loop, schedule

I have the follow problem:
i'm writing an chat bot in java and i want to call a method even x minutes.
So i read an "Timer.Schedule" is what i need. So i write the following method:

```
public function timerMethod()
{
    int time = 10;

    ...

    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerMethod();
            }
        }, 1000 * 60 * time // 1MSec * 1Sec * xMin
    );
}
```

At the beginning the loop works fine but after a few hours (i think it's after 10-15 hours) the loop dont work anymore...
I dont know why i dont work and dont get any error message :(

Can someone help me pleace???

Comment: Is it possible that an exception is thrown in `timerMethod()`? Try surrounding the call with with `try` `catch` and log / print any details of the exception thrown for eliminating this possibility,

Comment: i try but no exception... the terminal display no error or exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want code to run for x minutes, correct?

If so, convert the time you want the code to run for into milliseconds like this : 1 minute = 60000 ms. There is a method called System.currentTimeMillis(), this will return a value of miliseconds from the EPOCH date (Jan 1, 1970).

You can use a while loop like this:

`

```
int msTime = 60000; //1 Minute = 60000 MS
int doUntil = ms + System.currentTimeMillis(); //1 minute
while(System.currentTimeMillis() != doUntil)
{
   //Code here
   System.out.println(¨Hello World¨); //This will print Ḧello World for 60000ms

}
```

Comment: do you mean this code instead of my Timer().Schedule()?

Answer (score 1):

Mmm well first you can stop instantiating multiple times the `java.util.Timer()` variable. You only need one as an attribute of the class. The timerTask is the only one there that should be reinstantiated.

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

Now, surround your code inside the run function with try/catch:

```
            public void run() {
            try {
                timerMethod();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Are you calling that timerMethod just once? You can add to this code some prints too in order to check whenever you reschedule your function and when you run your method.

Comment: Try/Catch i tryed but nothing exception or error...
i have 3 other timer, can i use the same timer object or must i do for each timer an own object?